# find continuous range and pass values out of if loop

Tags: perl

I want to find a continuous range that all values are more than 0.3 . for example

```
A   1   10  0.2
A   20  40  0.4
A   60  75  0.5
A   90  100 0.55
A   200 205 0.43
A   211 270 0.8
A   450 511 0.1
A   513 550 0.0
B   1   10  0.6
B   50  200 0.7
B   300 350 0.8
B   400 500 0.9
B   600 711 0.4
B   800 900 0.2
```

output:

```
A   20  270
B   1   711
```

I tried:

```
while(<>){
        chomp($_);
        my @line = split("\t| ", $_);
        my $letter=$line[0];
        my @start;
        my @end;
                if($line[3]>0.3){
                        push (@start, $line[1]);
                        push (@end, $line[2]);

                        }
                if($line[3]<0.3){
                        next;}
                print $letter,"\t",$start[0],"\t",$end[-1],"\n";
                }
```

but I get:

```
A       20      40
A       60      75
A       90      100
A       200     205
A       211     270
B       1       10
B       50      200
B       300     350
B       400     500
B       600     711
```

But I want only first start and last end of each proper range

Comment: sorry if it was not clear. I want to print out start and end of a range congaing values more than 0.3.

Comment: Tip: `split(' ', $_)` (which can be written as `split`), splits on whitepsace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a hash?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %values;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($letter, $start, $end, $val) = split "\t| ";

    next if (defined $values{$letter}{skip_rest});

    if ($val > 0.3) {
        $values{$letter}{min} = $start
            if not defined $values{$letter}{min} or $values{$letter}{min} > $start;
        $values{$letter}{max} = $end
            if not defined $values{$letter}{max} or $values{$letter}{max} < $end;
    }
    elsif (defined $values{$letter}{min} and defined $values{$letter}{max}) {
        $values{$letter}{skip_rest} = "true";
    }
}

foreach my $letter (sort keys %values) {
    print "$letter\t$values{$letter}{min}\t$values{$letter}{max}\n";
}
```

Comment: does not check for a continuous range

Comment: Thanks @ysth, don't know how I missed it :P

Answer (score 3):

You don't say whether you want the first or last letter (or if you want to treat a letter change as ending a range) so I just do the first.

```
my $in_range;
my @ranges;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($letter, $start, $end, $value) = split /\t| /, $_;
    if ($value <= .3) {
        $in_range = undef;
    }
    elsif ($in_range) {
        $in_range->{'end'} = $end;
        push @{ $in_range->{'values'} }, $value;
    }
    else {
        $in_range = {
            'letter' => $letter,
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end,
            'values' => [ $value ],
        };
        push @ranges, $in_range;
    }
}

for my $range (@ranges) {
    print join( "\t",
        @$range{ qw/letter start end/ },
        scalar( @{ $range->{'values'} } ),
        join( ',', @{ $range->{'values'} } )
    ), "\n";
}
```

(updated per comment to show values)

Comment: how it is possible to put a counter to show how many values we grouped in a continuous range and also show the valuse. for example "A 20 270 5 0.4,0.5,0.55,0.43,0.8"